# Detect -nostdlib or just detect whether stdlib is available or not

Tags: c, gcc

I have a homework assignment that requires us to open, read and write to file using system calls rather than standard libraries. To debug it, I want to use std libraries when test-compiling the project. I did this:

```
#ifdef HOME
  //Home debug prinf function
  #include <stdio.h>
#else
  //Dummy prinf function
  int printf(const char* ff, ...) {
    return 0;
  }
#endif
```

And I compile it like this: `gcc -DHOME -m32 -static -O2 -o main.exe main.c`

Problem is that I with `-nostdlib` argument, the standard entry point is `void _start` but without the argument, the entry point is `int main(const char** args)`. You'd probably do this:

```
//Normal entry point
int main(const char** args) {
  _start();
}
//-nostdlib entry point
void _start() {
  //actual code
}
```

In that case, this is what you get when you compile without `-nostdlib`:

```
/tmp/ccZmQ4cB.o: In function `_start':
main.c:(.text+0x20): multiple definition of `_start'
/usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o:(.text+0x0): first defined here
```

Therefore I need to detect whether stdlib is included and do not define `_start` in that case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The low-level entry point is always `_start` for your system. With `-nostdlib`, its definition is omitted from linking so you have to provide one. Without `-nostdlib`, you must not attempt to define it; even if this didn't get a link error from duplicate definition, it would horribly break the startup of the standard library runtime.

Instead, try doing it the other way around:

```
int main() {
  /* your code here */
}
#ifdef NOSTDLIB_BUILD /* you need to define this with -D */
void _start() {
  main();
}
#endif
```

You could optionally add fake arguments to `main`. It's impossible to get the real ones from a `_start` written in C though. You'd need to write `_start` in asm for that.

Note that `-nostdlib` is a *linker* option, not compile-time, so there's no way to *automatically* determine at compile-time that that `-nostdlib` is going to be used. Instead just make your own macro and pass it on the command line as `-DNOSTDLIB_BUILD` or similar.

Comment: I'm not sure if this isn't too complicated for an SO answer, but how exactly does linker define `void _start`?

Comment: It doesn't. The default linker command line (when `-nostdlib` isn't used) includes a file usually named something like `crt1.o` that contains the definition of `_start`.